# $request->contactMail in blade template

Tags: php, laravel

I have contact form built in Laravel.

Using Mail to send it. Here is code:

Route:

```
Mail::to('contact@example.com')->send(new ContactWebmaster());
```

ContactWebmaster class

```
return $this->subject('Kontakt forma')->markdown('email.contactwebmaster');
```

email.contactwebmaster

```
@component('mail::message')

Thank you for contacting us.. (Example)

@endcomponent
```

In blade template contactwebmaster, I want to pass user's email passed in input text in the form.

Complete route for sending mail:

```
    Route::post('/contactMail', function (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'kontaktIme' => 'required',
        'kontaktMail' => 'required|email',
        'vasaPoruka' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/kontakt')
            ->withInput($request->input())
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }
    Mail::to('contact@example.com')->send(new ContactWebmaster());
    return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Uspešno ste poslali poruku!');

});
```

How to do this? I'm new in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#view-data)

There are two ways you may make data available to your view.

**Via Public Properties:**

```
public $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user= $user;
}
```

**Via The `with` Method:**

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('email.contactwebmaster')
                ->with([
                    'email' => $this->user->email,
                ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand something. In the docs is written __contruct(Order $order) and at the top use App\Order. In my case I don't have Order, or User, my variable is from blade template for the contact form.

Comment: That's how you pass varibales to views

Answer (score 0):

You can add that data to your `ContactWebmaster` mailable:

```
Mail::to('contact@example.com')->send(new ContactWebmaster($request->all()));
```

Then in your `ContactWebmaster`:

```
public $data;

constructor($data) {
   $this->data = $data;
}

public function build()
{
    $this->subject('Kontakt forma')->markdown('email.contactwebmaster', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
Mail::send('view name', ['data'=>$data], function($message)
                    {
                        $message->to('test@gmail.com', 'Email Message')->subject('Enquiry From Page!');
                    });
```